# Rally APIs with ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

We are migrating from @task to Rally and trying to change my REST api calls to work under Rally.
I am having trouble finding the syntax for sending the username/password via cfhttpparam for the purpose of getting the Rally SecurityToken.
My end result would be pulling the Rally hours by resource over a given time period.

i have found several curl examples but cant get a translation to work in ColdFusion using cfhttp

Comment: [Edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19098897/edit) to include the curl example and your attempted translation.

Comment: Show us some code, what you got and what you expected to get. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)